# How to use awk to print columns in a loop?

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I have a multiple-column text output from some command, and want to print the columns one at a time, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

typeset -i i=0
while [[ $i -lt 5 ]]; do
  <command 1> |awk '{print $i}' |<command 2>
  i=$i+1
done
```

I know `$i` is not the way to specify the i-th column in awk. What is the correct usage here?

Say, the output from `command 1` is something like:

```
"abc" "def" "ghi" "jkm"
"123" "456" "789" "0ab"
"erf" "fad" "dae" "kjh"
```

The value is not necessarily 3-character long. Here is just for example.

I want to get the 1st column to the 4th column in turn, to be used by `command 2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't do the loop in your question. because, this will execute same command (`command 1`) **n** times (**12** times in your example), just for extracting a value. If the `command 1` is expensive, your script would be slow. even if it is not expensive, it is not good practice, we **should not** do it like that.

I would suggest you execute cmd1 only once, and then convert the output of it into a format, which is easy to pass to commnd2. for example:

```
OUT1=$(command1||awk '{for (i=1;i<=4;i++)print $i}')
```

this will turn the output into each col in a line, like:

```
"abc"
"def"
"ghi"
"jkm"
"123"
"456"
"789"
"0ab"
"erf"
"fad"
"dae"
"kjh"
```

then you could work on the variable `$OUT1` with loop or whatever.

It is also possible to invoke the `command2` within awk. it depends on the requirement. if you don't want to catch output of cmd2, you could do:

```
$(command1||awk '{for (i=1;i<=4;i++)system("command2 "$i)}')
```

But again, this is depended on your logic/requirement.

Comment: Awesome suggestion! Yes, this new design would boost the performance tremendously. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still confused about one thing, why this `print $i` would print the i-th column in one line, instead of printing the whole i-th column?

Comment: Is there a way to `awk` out the output column by column, and then call `command 2` on each column (with the help of for-loop)? For example, I want to get `"abc"\n"123"\n"erf` first, and use this for the input of `command 2`. After that, feed `command 2` with `"def"\n"456"\n"fad"`, and so on.

Comment: yes, `cut` or `awk '{print $x}` x is index of column. you could save output of cmd1 into `O1` then apply the command on `O1` to get the column.

Comment: Tried to get such output, but in vain. Could you give me an example, Kent? The requirement here is to execute `command 1` only once, and to print its output column by column.

Comment: Ok, I try to explain it with an example. denghui ^_^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29126/discussion-between-kent-and-qiang-xu)

Answer (score 7):

You are getting confused between `$i` the shell variable and `$i` the i<sup>th</sup> field in `awk`.  You need to pass in the value of shell variable to `awk` in using `-v`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}; do 
    <command1> | awk -v i="$i" '{print $i}' | <command2>
done
```

This will let `command2` process each column from the output of `command1` separately.

Comment: Yes, it works if `i` starts from 1 to 5. But if I used the original while-loop, and iterate `i` from 0 to 4, and use `awk -v i="$i+1" '{print $i}'`, it broke again. Any remedy here?

Comment: Note that `$0` has a meaning in `awk`, but it means 'the whole input line', not a field within that line.  If you want columns 1-4 in the awk output, you either provide values 1..4 as the value for `i`, or you use `awk -v i=$i '{print $(i+1)}'`.  But your loop as written in the going to generate 5 lots of output from the 4 fields, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @QiangXu so just initialize the shell variable `$i` to `1` then.